# macOS Monterey - give nfsd root access

Tags: macos, nfs

Hello I'm trying to set up full disk access to nfsd and cannot find it in the privacy section for system preferences. Is there a way to do this via command line?

P.S. nfsd is enabled and running
Environment: macOS Monterey (12.3)
Chip: Apple M1 Pro

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlock the Prefs pane, then drag & drop it into the list [& check it if it doesn't automatically].

You can only do that on the prefs that have the +/- buttons at the bottom.